# How to run Websphere Portal/portlets locally from within RAD to debug

Tags: debugging, websphere, local, portal, ibm-rad

I have been looking around on the internet how to setup a local Portal environment together with the RAD IDE, I found threads like [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/message.jspa?messageID=13903296#13903296) but that's a thread of the ancient history (speaking in IT terms) or only refers to optimizing Portal with RAD ([here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/07/0327_riordan/index.html)). Currently I have RAD 8.0.4.1 running and I can run a WAS-instance, but I can't manage to get the Portal-environment run locally. I read that in the past there was some sort of specific Portal Test Environment, but with the newer RAD do I have to install a full Portal? And where to get it? I cannot find a good reference anywhere.

I want to debug my portlets locally in as local Portal-context. Currently the portlets are deployed on a remote Portal-server. This costs time (package WAR, upload, refresh nodes et cetera). So I want to run our Portal locally including its portlets.

In RAD I can define new servers and can see the option "WebSphere Portal v6.1 Server on WAS 7", but it requires me to define a Server runtime environment. This opens a new popup where I have to specify:

- WebSphere Portal Location
- WebSphere Application Server Location

I have my runtimes installed in "IBM\SDP\runtimes" which contains the following folders "base_stub, base_v6_stub, base_v7, base_v7_stub, base_v8_stub, base_v61_stub, portal_v61_stub, updi_v7x, updi_v70, wsdk". Whatever location I try to point to, it keeps giving an error message: `"The Portal Server installation is not correct"`.

I have the following questions:

- what do I need to run/debug my portal with its portlets locally?
- the fact I see portal_v61_stub in my runtime directory, means a Portal server is not installed? My IBM installation manager doesn't specifically show an option to install a Portal Server.
- is it possible to run portlet/portal locally and use hotswapping to immediately see the changes in the code/view?
- where can I download/install the required software?
- I heard that you need a very heavy machine to do portal/debug stuff locally (I am running on a 8 GB/Intel E8400 at 3.00 GHz.)
- how can I transfer the current Portal-setup which is running on a remote server to my local system (mirroring/just copy files?)

Comment: I would +10 this if I could.  Developing on our DEV environments (as opposed to locally) is a painfully slow process.

Answer (score 2):

Few things,

RAD is a tool to develop application developed on Eclipse. It doesn't come with any server application. You need to install your WAS/Portal Server.

RAD supports Portal development and hence it has got stubs but you wont be able to deploy an application without a server.

> what do I need to run/debug my portal with its portlets locally?

You need an Application server installed on your machine. Or Connect to a remote server.

> the fact I see portal_v61_stub in my runtime directory, means a Portal server is not installed? My IBM installation manager doesn't specifically show an option to install a Portal Server.

No. Server is not installed. You dont need IBM Installation Manager for installing server. It's for RAD.

> is it possible to run portlet/portal locally and use hotswapping to immediately see the changes in the code/view?

Yes it is, if you have a server installed.

> where can I download/install the required software?

You can download the express version of server. But if otherwise if you are IBM business partner you can download from their website.

> I heard that you need a very heavy machine to do portal/debug stuff locally (I am running on a 8 GB/Intel E8400 at 3.00 GHz.)

3 GB is fine for running RAD and IBM Websphere Portal Server. ( I am running it right now with many other applications ) But for best result use 4 GB RAM.

> how can I transfer the current Portal-setup which is running on a remote server to my local system (mirroring/just copy files?)

You need to open your RAD and attach a server to it. Go to `windows->preferences->servers->Webpshere`

Comment: @Udo: thank you for your feedback, I come from a Spring/Tomcat/Hibernate/IntelliJ environment and know my way around there, but IBM has all kinds of tools/documentation pointing in different directions. I will first try to download the portal server from the IBM site and try to get that running. Not sure about your last response; can I just point now already to our current remote Portal-server to (hot) deploy?

Comment: @Tjeerd I didn't give any feedback. HP24 answers looked ok. I'm unsure about the remote deployment. You have to check it yourself. I'm just using the RAD occasionly.

Comment: @Tjeerd Sure you can do remote deploy.Check this link for more information http://www.webspheretools.com/sites/webspheretools.nsf/docs/Remote%20debugging%20for%20a%20%20WebSphere%20Web%20application%20using%20RAD Also check for IBM redbooks which should help you understand how to use/configure/optimize your RAD and local/remote environment. This one is for RAD 6.0 you can check for your specific version of RAD. http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg246681.html Hope it helps.